# Overflow-x on same browser, different platform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery slider which needs to be centered in my body; this slider acts as a changing background (fades into one another). I have no overflow problem on my computer (iMac), but on my nexus 7, my body is much wider to fit the whole image. In both cases, I have the latest version of Firefox.

Here's my CSS:

```
#grosse_photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -552px;
    height: 597px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

My images are all 1904px wide x 597px high.

I've tried making `#grosse_photo` relative and absolute position my images from there, but they don't center. I've also tried `overflow-x: hidden` to all elements (`#grosse_photo`, `body` and `html`) but don't seem to get anywhere.

If it helps any, this is the jQuery animation I'm using:
http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

It has served me well in the past, but this is the first time I'm using it as a background.

Comment: Is grosse_photo the id for your images or the slideshow? Adding the html to your question will help a lot.

Comment: `#grosse_photo` is a wrapper around the slideshow; I wanted to place it behind everything in the center and then have the slideshow within `#grosse_photo`. So it would be `<div id="grosse_photo"><div id="slideshow"><!-- slideshow here --></div></div>`

Comment: Does the Nexus 7 need a `meta viewport` element?

Comment: In both cases, this is the same html file with no meta viewport set.